# Fourier transform of $ |\cos(2\pi f_0 t)| $?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I have trouble understanding how to find the Fourier transform of $|\cos(2\pi f_0 t)|$.
If I have $\cos(2\pi f_0 t)$, I can see it as $\frac{1}{2}\cdot[e^{i2\pi f_0 t}+e^{-i2\pi f_0 t}] $ and its transform is the sum of two Dirac deltas, but what if I have the function written above?

$|\cos(2\pi f_0 t)|$ should be periodic in $ t $ with period $ \frac{1}{2f_0}=\frac{T_0}{2} $ .
From the definition, $ x(t)= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} X_k \cdot e^{-i2\pi f_0 kt} $ and $ X_k= \frac{1}{T_0} \cdot \int_{-\frac{T_0}{2}}^{+\frac{T_0}{2}}x(t) \cdot e^{-i2\pi f_0 kt} dt $ where $ T_0 $ is the generic period. So $X_k= \frac{2}{T_0} \cdot \int_{-\frac{T_0}{4}}^{+\frac{T_0}{4}} cos(2\pi f_0 t) \cdot e^{-i2\pi f_0 kt} dt $ . If I try to solve this integral, the result I get is $ 0 $ . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Up to a rescaling in time, you are looking for the [Fourier transform of the absolute value of a cosine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097762/find-the-fourier-series-of-the-absolute-value-of-cosine) a question which is already answered in the given link. There is also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697843/fourier-series-for-cosx) which might be helpful.

Comment: @cs89 Hello and thank you for your suggestions, but I still don't understand how to proceed. Regarding the answers linked in your previous comment, why do we have to consider the whole $ 2\pi $ interval when the absolute value is periodic with period $ \pi $ in $ x $ ?

Comment: You don't "have to", you "can". If a function is periodic of period $P$, then you can represent it as the Fourier series $f(x) = \sum c_n e^{\frac{2i\pi n x}{P}}$. It can happen that your function is also, at the same time, by chance, periodic of period $P/2$, or $P/7$, or whatever and thus you can also represent it as another Fourier series $f(x) = \sum c_n' e^{\frac{2i\pi n x}{P/2}}$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Going back to my initial question, we have a period of $ \frac{T_0}{2} $ and  I am stuck to that point.

Comment: Don't you get $0$ because you forgot the absolute value around the cosine inside the integral?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Maybe I finally found my mistake: I thought that since the period of $ |\cos(2\pi f_0 t)| $ was $ \frac{1}{2f_0}= \frac{T_0}{2} $ , then the $ f_0 $ inside the cosine was equal to $ \frac{2}{T_0} $. If the value of $ f_0 $ remains $ \frac{1}{T_0} $ then the integral is not 0 anymore and $ X_{2p} = \frac{(-1)^{p+1}}{\pi} \cdot \frac{2}{4p^2 -1 } $, because the odd terms are 0. What do you think?

Comment: It looks consistent with the other links indeed.

Comment: That's good then. Thank you for your help.